# Circles misplaced in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to draw a circle on an image in MATLAB with given X,Y coordinates and radius. Here's the chuck of code of method that draws multiple circles for me -

```
function circle( Xs, Ys, Rs, LineWidth, LineColor)
    radius = Rs;
    centerX = Xs;
    centerY = Ys;

    for i=1:length(centerX)
        rectangle('Position',[centerX(i), centerY(i), radius(i), radius(i)],...
        'Curvature',[1,1],...
        'LineWidth',LineWidth,...
        'LineStyle','-',...
        'EdgeColor',LineColor);
    end
end
```

But whenever I see the circles in an image, I see that the circles are a little bit misplaced from the given coordinates (for example, they moved a little bit right/down). How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are drawing is actually a [rectangle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rectangle.html). But you have a curvature defined, which makes it look like a circle. The circle is then defined by a bounding box with the coordinates of the rectangle. The Position of the rectangle is the upper left corner (or in a regular plot the lower left corner) and what you called the radius is actually the width and height of that bounding box.

This is what I mean:

```
>> figure, imshow(I)
>> rectangle('Position',[100,100,120,120],'Curvature',[1,1])
>> rectangle('Position',[100,100,120,120],'Curvature',[0,0],'EdgeColor','r')
>> axis on
```

This code will produce a circle and a rectangle both in the same position defined by the same rectangle coordinates in the upper left corner. The red one is the bounding box I am speaking of.
[image]

Edit: If you don't want to use the rectangle function you could maybe do the following:

```
>> figure,imshow(I)
>> hold on
>> plot(centerX+radius*sin(0:0.1:2*pi),centerY+radius*cos(0:0.1:2*pi))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes a lot more sense! Is there any other way I can draw a circle for several points and radius?

Comment: I added an alternative to the rectangle function. I am not aware of a build-in MATLAB function.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

function circle( Xs, Ys, Rs, LineWidth, LineColor)

```
radius = Rs;
centerX = Xs;
centerY = Ys;
xStart = centerX - radius;
yStart = centerY - radius;

for i=1:length(centerX)

    rectangle('Position',[xStart(i) , yStart(i) , radius(i), radius(i)],...
    'Curvature',[1,1],...
    'LineWidth',LineWidth,...
    'LineStyle','-',...
    'EdgeColor',LineColor);

end
```

### end

I hope this will work.
By subtracting the radius from the center points we can get the starting point(Top left corner) of the rectangle with curvature [1,1], that is nothing but the circle.